# Redirecting Test Output

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm using a bash script to automate a set of tests for some other code.  The script looks like this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
  cd ~/BuildBot
  rm -rf program        # Remove the directory each time to test installation
  git clone /localrepo/
  cd ~/into/program
  python2.6 setup.py build_ext -i
  cd tests

  python runtest.py >& ~/into/reptest/runtest-all.out.$i
  echo $? > ~/into/reptest/runtest-all.exit.$i

done
```

When run like this, the script does what I want - shows me a Wall of Text, and saves it to a file in the directory reptest.  Now that I've tested installation, it's getting annoying to have to wait for the whole program to reinstall.  However, when I cut the script down to

```
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
  cd ~/into/program/tests

  python runtest.py >& ~/into/reptest/runtest-all.out.$i
  echo $? > ~/into/reptest/runtest-all.exit.$i

done
```

The script hangs, nothing happens, the shell waits on a blank line until I Ctrl-C it.  What happens to the output?  How do I get back my Wall of Text?

Comment: You're not happening to use windows/Cygwin and have by mistake switched to the \r\n line endings?

Comment: Btw: I guess the output files are not created att all?

Comment: You don't need to use seq you can use: "for i in {1..10}". Change "python" to "echo" and see what happens. That would eliminate python or runtest.py as culprits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python runtest.py >& ~/into/reptest/runtest-all.out.$i
```

Redirects both stdout and stderr from runtest.py into the file ~/into/reptest/runtest-all.out.$i. Your wall of text comes from the statements you've pruned away.

What you're interested in are probably something like:

```
( python runtest.py 2>&1 ) | tee ~/into/reptest/runtest-all.out.$i
```

Which runs python runtest.py in a subshell and redirect it's stderr to stdout, then pipe the output from that subshell into "tee ~/into/reptest/runtest-all.out.$i". tee saves it's stdin to the file given as an argument in addition to copying it to stdout.

As to why your programs waits until you send it SIGINT, I'm not sure, I don't see anything bash-related which should make your script hang until interrupted.